# Live in a state/situation/circumstance

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language, phrase-choice, colloquial-language

Do you think we can say someone is living in a situation/state/circumstance? If things are going bad in our life and we have bad life circumstances etc, can we say any of these sentences?

> I live in a bad state.

> I live in a bad situation.

> I live in a bad circumstance.

> I live in bad circumstances.

Do you think it is okay to use these phrases with the verb “live”? I think we can say we live in bad conditions, but I wonder about these sentences. Can they ever be said by native English speakers depending on what they mean/what the context is. I think the fourth sentence is usable but I am not sure about especially the first two sentences I gave.

Comment: "I _am_ in a bad state/situation" would be more idiomatic. _Circumstances_ in this context is always plural.

Comment: As @KateBunting says, we don't usually use "live" in this context. If you said "I live in a bad state" in the U.S., someone might ask, "Then why don't you just move to another state?"